# Dataset is not compatible in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server

I built a program using visual studio 2010, connected to a SQL Server 2005. I used a dataset to build table adapters and create queries. When I changed to visual studio 2013 with SQL Server 2012, I can't open the dataset anymore. When trying to open the designer I get this message:

> The dataset designer in this version of Visual Studio is not
>   Compatible with SQL Server Compact connections.

Moreover, I get errors when rebuilding the project as all the tableadapters in the dataset doesn't exist.

I am using windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bit

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896141(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error when I tried to open a dataset in the designer which was created using an older version.

I solved it using the following Visual Studio Plugin:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1

After removing the write protection of my data set I was able to open and edit it through the plugin.